# google sign-in post redirected back to login

Tags: authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I added the google sign in button and try to post the token back to the server. Created a Filter and a controller for the post and also in the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter defined it as  .antMatchers("/google-sign-in/**").permitAll().
but my post is redirected back to the login page...

```
.antMatchers("/google-sign-in/**").permitAll()
.and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage(LOGIN_PAGE_URL)

function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId());
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/google-sign-in?idtoken=' + id_token);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.onload = function() {
        console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
}
```

what am I doing wrong?